# Display out of stock options of configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

Greetings to all developers!

I need your help! I am following [this](https://siven76.com/2013/04/19/magento-show-out-of-stock-options-of-configurable-products/) tutorial to display out of stock options of my configurable product. What we want to achieve is even when certain sizes of a product are sold out, we want to show that these options are available, but are currently out of stock(and therefore greyed out). By default Magento does not display these options at all. By following the above mentioned tutorial, I am able to show these options, but the problem is I think this bit of code:

```
  // disable out of stock options
   if(this.getOptionLabel(options[i], options[i].price).indexOf('stock') !== -1) {
      $(element.options[index]).addClassName('disabled');
      element.options[index].disabled = true;
   }
   // END: disable out of stock options


 in the file js/varien/configurable.js
```

Because out of stock options are not disabled.
Any idea what could be wrong?

BTW I tried to open debugger on my mozilla browser and look into configurable.js, I set up some break points, but execution of the javascript does not stop at my break points, any idea why?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!